# MySQL Exception: Execute SQL Transaction

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, anorm

I am trying to commit a sql transaction to MySQL but I get myself past an `MySQLSyntaxErrorException`.

The code I am using is:

```
implicit connection => 
        SQL("""
            start transaction;
            insert into projects(id_user, name, description) values({idUser}, {name}, {description});
            set @last_id = last_insert_id();
            insert into assigned(id_user, id_project) values({idUser}, @last_id);
            commit;
        """)
    .on('idUser -> idUser,
        'name -> project.name,
        'description -> project.description
    ).execute()
```

The exception I get:

```
[MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into projects(id_user, name, description) values(1, 'First inserted proje' at line 1]
```

I am starting to think that I can't execute such statements at all with Anorm.

Comment: Are you sure the insert query is not causing syntax errors?

Comment: @VaibhavDesai I even reduced the whole statement to `start transaction; commit;` and it's the same exception.

Comment: Did you set auto-commit to false before starting the transaction? Also, what error does it give when you just had the transactional statements in there?

Comment: Also, try using a "begin; " statement before "begin transaction;".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use transaction that way. You have to understand that anorm is simply a wrapper around existing jdbc libraries. By default, when using the **withConnection** and **SQL** :

```
DB.withConnection { conn => 
    SQL("...
}
```

Your query is transformed using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). Meaning the `;` chars are causing errors.

Thus, if you want to use transaction, you have to use [anorm's mecanism](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaDatabase) for that.

```
DB.withTransaction { conn =>
    SQL("...
}
```

Comment: and then I use on `SQL` statement for all or do I write an `SQL` declaration for each statement?

Comment: That depends on your application. If you need to execute several times the same query, write one that is repeated. Otherwise use a SQL statement per statement.